# broken material and shader graph settings after I combined prefabs from different projects

Tags: unity-game-engine, metadata, project, prefab

So I made 3 different projects which contain contents of some meshes with materials, shader graphs, and set animation and keyframes using timeline. Then I export contents as one prefab for each projects, so I got 3 different prefabs. Then I created a new project, imported those prefabs, and what happened was I got broken materials and shaders. A difference from normal shader issues which shows us pink meshes, it seems all image textures are correctly linked but all shader graph animation I set the keyframes on the timeline is lost or weirdly changed.

-I found out that I used same or similar shader graph setting through out all three different projects with the same file name of the shader graph. I guessed this might caused the problem, so I differenciated those file names, re-prefabed, imported again, the same crush.

-I also found out someone said using GIT can prevent these kind of data crushing problems and also it can fix it at this stage. But I didn't try using GIT yet, cause I've never used it before so if I'm going use GIT, it might take time to get used it.

-If anybody faced problem similar to this, please help me with any insights or solutions. Oh, also this is my first time using SOF platform, so I'm sorry if I gave any lack of information with this question. If you point out or need more details about the issue, I'll add more details as far as I can.